# How is it possible for "rendered output" to show more changes than "markdown"?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just started reviewing SEs this morning and found (for the first time) that the "rendered output" option displayed *more* changes than the "markdown" option,

Markdown,
[image]

Rendered output,
[image]

I always thought the "markdown" option would show *all* changes (which is why I keep it as my default view), but is that actually true? How and why did this happen (a bug perhaps)?

Comment: A line feed was removed before `material`. The markdown diff does not show it because newlines are invisible, so there is no way to strike them out.

Comment: So then in "rendered output" it just strikes out the word next to the missing newline instead?

Comment: Indeed, it strikes out (newline + `material`) and highlights (`material` only). Markdown view does not do the same. The diff algorithms used may be different.

Comment: Right, actually after looking more closely I see the space behind "`material`" is also highlighted. Thanks.